# Retrieving a data framework from panda library

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hey one quick and very easy question for all of you I am sure! Related to pandas & dataframes

So basically I just have to create a dataframe that contains the GDP Data from an already imported panda library. There is a dictionary under the word "links" containing the csv file with the data. The actual question is the following

" The dictionary links contain the CSV files with all the data. The value for the key GDP is the file that contains the GDP data. The value for the key unemployment contains the unemployment data.

```
links={'GDP':'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/projects/coursera_project/clean_gdp.csv',\'unemployment':'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/projects/coursera_project/clean_unemployment.csv'
```

**strong text**Question 1: Create a dataframe that contains the GDP data and display the first five rows of the dataframe.
Use the dictionary links and the function pd.read_csv to create a Pandas dataframes that contains the GDP data.
Hint: links["GDP"] contains the path or name of the file.**strong text**

```
links={'GDP':'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/projects/coursera_project/clean_gdp.csv'}
links_frame=pd.DataFrame(links, index=[0])
path_csv=links
df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
```

Writing [52] gives me the following errors:

What am I doing wrong?!! I am sure it is very simple but as I am very new to this I would appreciate your help!!!! Thank you all Smile Smile Smile

---

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in 2 links_frame=pd.DataFrame(links, index=[0]) 3 path_csv=links ----> 4 df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision) 700 skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines) 701 --> 702 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) 703 704 parser_f.name = name

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) 411 compression = _infer_compression(filepath_or_buffer, compression) 412 filepath_or_buffer, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer( --> 413 filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression) 414 kwds['compression'] = compression 415

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode) 230 if not is_file_like(filepath_or_buffer): 231 msg = "Invalid file path or buffer object type: {_type}" --> 232 raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer))) 233 234 return filepath_or_buffer, None, compression, False

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use `urllib` in python.

```
import urllib.request
df = pd.read_csv(urllib.request.urlopen("https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/projects/coursera_project/clean_gdp.csv")))
```

or else

```
df = pd.read_csv(urllib.request.urlopen(links['GDP']))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a typo in your links dictionary, there is a \ before 'unemployment'

As far as I understood your question you want to do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd

links={'GDP':'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/projects/coursera_project/clean_gdp.csv','unemployment':'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/projects/coursera_project/clean_unemployment.csv'}
df_objects = {}

for key in links:
    df_objects[key] = pd.read_csv(links[key])

for key in df_objects:
    print(df_objects[key])
```

Output:

```
    date  level-current  level-chained  change-current  change-chained
0   1948          274.8         2020.0            -0.7            -0.6
1   1949          272.8         2008.9            10.0             8.7
2   1950          300.2         2184.0            15.7             8.0
3   1951          347.3         2360.0             5.9             4.1
4   1952          367.7         2456.1             6.0             4.7
..   ...            ...            ...             ...             ...
64  2012        16155.3        15354.6             3.6             1.8
65  2013        16691.5        15612.2             4.4             2.5
66  2014        17427.6        16013.3             4.0             2.9
67  2015        18120.7        16471.5             2.7             1.6
68  2016        18624.5        16716.2             4.2             2.2

[69 rows x 5 columns]
    date  unemployment
0   1948      3.750000
1   1949      6.050000
2   1950      5.208333
3   1951      3.283333
4   1952      3.025000
..   ...           ...
64  2012      8.075000
65  2013      7.358333
66  2014      6.158333
67  2015      5.275000
68  2016      4.875000

[69 rows x 2 columns]
```

My solution is pretty simple and self-explanatory.